# GNU assembler preprocessor define

Tags: gnu, gnu-assembler

I have two questions:

1. How do I use CPP (C Preprocessor) with GNU's AS
2. How do I use "continuation lines" (like `some line \ next line`)?

For the first, I know you can use `.include` instead of `#include`, but `#define` doesn't work (and I don't know the equivalent). File extension `.S` is supposed to force it to use the preprocessor, same with `g++ -x assembler-with-cpp`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make a single question per post, and make your title very precise. I don't reproduce you with `gcc in.S`: preprocessor does get uesd in that case.

Answer (score 6):

As indicated by @Ciro Santilli, GNU AS does not perform CPP-like preprocessing. For this you need to assemble your file with `gcc`, like `gcc in.S`. Doing so enables both the CPP preprocessor and the continuation line symbol.

Otherwise, the AS directive that is roughly equivalent to `#define` for GNU AS stand-alone is `.set` (to define new symbols, see [AS manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Set.html#Set)).

Comment: Perhaps it's worth to stress that gcc preprocesses assembler source if and only if the extension is `.S`. That means with `gcc in.s`  the C preprocessor is **not** called.